# Adding Subdomain on Google Analytics - Filtered view v/s Creating new property

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website setup on Google Analytics and am tracking visits there. I recently launched a product and this is a subdomain on my website. I want to track vistors independently on both my main website and my product subdomain.

From my reading, I realize there are two ways of approaching this. One would be to go for a filtered view and the other to create a new property for the Subdomain and show both of them as two different views.

What I am trying to get is a clean un-cluttered view for my subdomain and most of the traffic on my subdomain will not interact with the main website or go to pages on it.

Coming to my question, should I add the subdomain as a filter or create a new property for it? All I want is easy manipulation of data, run reports and at all costs reduce clutter and mixing on my main website and subdomain stats.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you'll get a few answers here, but in my experience, using a filtered view for a sub-domain has worked best. You don't need to worry about configurations for a new property, and all it takes is an Include filter to get the desired reports. Filters, when used properly, can segregate data, for example, between your main site and the sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a new property.  Just create a new View for the existing property and add an Include filter for the subdomain.  You can also add an Exclude filter to the existing View to remove subdomain traffic.